# What does happen when a python list is added as a row element in a csv file?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm structuring a csv CRUD in Python and eventually I needed to save Python lists in a "cell" of a  table. The saving succeeded as I'm able to read the cell as the Python list that it is.

**But I was wandering: what happens inside the conversion of "Python list" to "csv cell"?**

As I externally open the csv file, the lists are saved as textual data like in "['item1', 'item2...]", with the brackets included in the cell content.

So, if anyone could answer this conceptual question, I'd appreciate.

Comment: I feel that what you get is the string representation of the data. i.e. `str(["a", "b"])` --> `"['a', 'b']"`. This is however just what I feel happens and not an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of writing non-string-objects using the `csv`-module is documented [in the `csv` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect):

> All other non-string data are stringified with str() before being written.

That is, all objects (except `None` and `str` itself) are converted to their string-representation by means of their respective [`str()`-implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Str) before being escaped+written.

This behavior is implemented [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/178919cf2132a67bc03ae5994769d93cfb7e2cd3/Modules/_csv.c#L1282C19-L1282C31).

Comment: Thanks, pal. Well documented answer, despite the answer in itself is simple. I'll wait for other answers, but yours already states it clearly.

Comment: @GeovaniLopesDias, I don't understand what you are saying. If this has been auto-translated, try forming shorter sentences...

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. What I've tried to say is that your answer was already useful in coding, and not just a information purely.

The usefulness that I've mentioned earlier lies in a problem that I just faced: I wasn't being able to properly add itens in a cell of a csv file which value was a list. But knowing that lists are "stringified" helped me to solve the issue.

PS: It was not an auto-translation, I'm just struggling to communicate in a foreign language by my own.

Comment: @GeovaniLopesDias, all good